# How to print a single JSON element

Tags: php, json

I'm new to JSON, but I'm trying to figure out but I'm getting an error for a simple print out.

I want to print out the score as an easy start. I've been reading about JSON and I don't see what im doing wrong.

**Error Message:**

PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /testing.php on line 11

```
 <?php


$string = file_get_contents('URL');

$json = json_decode($string);


foreach ($json['pos'] as $score)
  {
   echo "pos:". $score['score'] ."\n";
  };

print_r($json);

  ?>


  {
  "pos": [
   {
     "pos": "1",
     "name": "Sarah",
     "game": "a",
     "score": "-10",
     "examscore": "-5"
   },
   {
     "pos": "T2",
     "name": "Brian ",
     "game": "F*",
     "score": "-8",
     "examscore": "-3"
   },
    {
    "pos": "T2",
     "name": "Joe",
     "game": "F*",
     "score": "-8",
     "examscore": "-1"
   },
  {
     "pos": "WD"
  }
 ] 
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your foreach loop should read:

```
foreach ($json->pos as $score) {
   echo "pos: " .$score->score ."\n";
};
```

Let's understand the JSON first. If you print it `print_r($string);` you will get:

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [pos] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [pos] => 1
                    [name] => Sarah
                    [game] => a
                    [score] => -10
                    [examscore] => -5
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [pos] => T2
                    [name] => Brian 
                    [game] => F*
                    [score] => -8
                    [examscore] => -3
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [pos] => T2
                    [name] => Joe
                    [game] => F*
                    [score] => -8
                    [examscore] => -1
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [pos] => WD
                )

        )

)
```

It is important to note that by default `json_decode(string)` returns an **OBJECT**

In the example above, `$json` is an object, and `[pos]` is an array. Whenever you access the member of an **Object**, you use the format: `$object->member`

Even though `[pos]` is an array, it is still a member of the object `$json` 
If you look at the JSON print out above, you can see that `[pos]` is actually an array of objects!. The `$object->member` formula would apply here for accessing each of its members (name, game, score ,etc).

Hope this helps.

Comment: makes more sense thanks, same error tho :/ - 
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /testing.php on line 12
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /testing.php on line 12

Comment: Why do you say .$score->score  ? when $score is not an object?

Comment: `$score` IS an object. If you look above, `pos` is an array of 4 different objects. In your foreach loop, you are accessing each one of those objects one at a time. Those individual objects are referred to as `$score`, specified in the foreach loop.

Comment: If you wanted to access only the second test score, you would do so by:
`$json->pos[1]->score`  Where 1 specifies the location of the object within the pos array.

Answer (score 0):

By default the json_decode return you not an array but an StdClass object if you don't specify the second argument as "true".
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

So if you want use the json_decode result as an array

Replace this

```
$json = json_decode($string);
```

By this

```
$json = json_decode($string, true);
```

**EDIT :**

In your foreach you try to display the $score['score'] but your last item in the json does not contain the key "score".

Replace

```
echo "pos:". $score['score'] ."\n";
```

By this

```
if(isset($score['score'])) { echo "pos:". $score['score'] ."\n"; }
```

Hope it will help you.